# ionRangeSlider bind two sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, slideshow

I have problem with bind two sliders, here it is what i have:
View:

```
                                <div ion-range-slider range-options="onHourOptions"></div>
                                    <p>The value so far is: <span>{{hourValue | number: 2}}$/h</span></p>

                                    <div ion-range-slider range-options="onMonthOptions"></div>
                                    <p>The value so far is: <span>{{monthValue| number: 2}}$</span></p>
```

Controller:

```
   $scope.onHourOptions = {
        min: 0,
        max: 90,
        type: 'single',
        step: 0.1,
        postfix: " $/h ",
        prettify: true,
        hasGrid: true,
        onChange: function (data) {
            $scope.hourValue = data.fromNumber;
            $scope.monthValue = data.fromNumber*168;
            $scope.$apply();
        },
    };

    $scope.onMonthOptions = {
            min: 1600,
            max: 15000,
            type: 'single',
            step: 10,
            postfix: " $ ",
            prettify: false,
            hasGrid: true,
            onChange: function (data) {
                $scope.monthValue = data.fromNumber;
                $scope.hourValue = data.fromNumber/168;
                $scope.$apply();
            },
        };
```

And my directive for slider:

```
function ionRangeSlider() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            rangeOptions: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.ionRangeSlider(scope.rangeOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

Now i would like to have something like this: When user change the value of payment for month then automatically the value of payment for hour will be updated. I have no idea how can i achieve this. I was trying to add to event something like this $scope.onHourOptions.from = data.fromNumber/168; but nothing was happens.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?